# C struct - member function accessing variable of parent struct

Tags: c, oop, struct

**In C++ you could do:**

```
class Person{
public:
    int ID;
    char* name;
    void Display(){
        cout << "Person " << name << " ID: " << ID << endl;
    }
}
```

Where the member function can access other variables in a class, is there anyway to do the same with a struct in C?

Comment: C has no concept of member functions

Comment: Well, you could have a pointer to a function as a member of a `struct`.

Comment: C++ provides the (implicit) `this` pointer to provide access to the members of the instance of the class.  You’ll have to simulate that (or, rather, `this`) in your C code.

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ code:

```
class Person {
public:
    int ID;
    char* name;
    void Display() {
        cout << "Person " << name << " ID: " << ID << endl;
    }
}
...
Person person;
...
person.Display();
...
```

In C there are no member functions, but similar code in C could look like this:

```
struct Person {
  int ID;
  char* name;
}

void Display(struct Person *this) {
   printf("Person %s ID: %d\n", this->name, this->ID);
}

...
struct Person person;
...
Display(&Person);
...
```

Comment: I guess a macro that turns ```foo.bar()``` into ```bar(foo)``` would work

Answer (score 0):

c is not a object oriented language, but you can do something like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>

typedef void (*DoRunTimeChecks)();

struct student  
{  
    char name[20];  
    DoRunTimeChecks func;
};  

void Print(char name[])
{
    printf("Printing student information\n");  
    printf("Name: %s",name);  
}

void main ()  
{  
    struct student s = {"shriram", Print}; 
    s.func = Print;
    s.func(s.name);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... function pointers in a C struct is not the C equivalence of normal methods, at most virtual methods.